# f# for loop continue

Tags: for-loop, f#, f#-interactive

I want after `else` the loop to continue, so the list will be filled and after that return list

```
let isPoli num =
    let x = string num
    let fhf = x.Substring(0, (int) (x.Length / 2))

    let shf =
        x.Substring((int) (x.Length / 2), (int) (x.Length / 2))
        |> Seq.rev
        |> Seq.toArray
        |> System.String

    if fhf = shf then true else false


let biggestPoliProduct (range: list<int>) =
    let acc = []

    for i in range do
        for j in range do
            if isPoli (i * j) then (i * j) :: acc
            else []
    acc

biggestPoliProduct [ 1 .. 100 ]
```

Comment: The expression `(i * j) :: acc` does not modify the value of `acc`. It creates a completely new list and then does nothing with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good situation for a [list comprehension](https://brandewinder.com/2011/09/23/Fun-with-List-comprehensions/):

```ml
let biggestPoliProduct (range: list<int>) =
    [
        for i in range do
            for j in range do
                if isPoli (i * j) then
                    yield (i * j)
    ]
```

No `else` branch needed.